# Authentication failure. Retrying... in Vagrantfile while using a custom created box

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I use the following command to package a VM,

```
vagrant package --base VMID —-output builder.box
```

My Vagrantfile looks as follows,

```
box = "centos/7"
prefix_ip_addr = "174.10.10."

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = box 
    builder_ip = "%s100" % [prefix_ip_addr]
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.ssh.insert_key = false

    config.vm.define :builder do |builder|
        # Setup builder VM and IP
        builder.vm.hostname = "builder"
        builder.vm.network :private_network, ip: builder_ip

        # Setup builder VM system requirements
        builder.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v| 
            v.memory = 1024 * 16
            v.cpus = 8 
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1","on"]
            v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
        end 
    end 
end
```

then I use the created the box to up another machine, that Vagrantfile looks like follows,

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.ssh.forward_agent = true
    config.vm.define :builder1 do |builder|
        builder.vm.box = "package.box"
    end 
end
```

But I am getting this error,

```
builder1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
builder1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
builder1: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This         means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest     machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time     period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Please help I am stuck at this error for a long time now. :(

Comment: Show me tomorrow. I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but I just started with vagrant myself and ran into this issue. for those who might also find yourself here, I just added the following to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.boot_timeout = 60
```

For the op, I might also check to see if you need to set the config.ssh.username and the config.ssh.password directives as well.